# Disable Touch on Background Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Main `FragmentActivity` that displays the main app `fragments`.  I have one particular fragment that I open on top of the "behind" main Fragment.  It only slide about 90% over with an animation.  My problem is this:

In that small 10% of the "behind" fragment that still shows through, you can manipulate it.  For example, it's a ListView, so I can scroll.

Is there a way to "turn off" or make the background fragment inactive here no touch responses happen?

Comment: I am unable to choose an answer because I have went in a different direction that does not use the above method.  So feel free to let the community upvote the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to Shashidhar Manchu answser:
Add:

### android:clickable="true" android:background="#000"

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:clickable="true">

<View
            android:id="@+id/sampleChild"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The background is optional, but without it, the fragment in the background will be visible.

Answer (score 3):

return true for that view in ontouchlistener. or you can make transaprent layout (with fill parent height and width in xml)
when fragment added make your transaperent layout clickable true and when fragament removed make it false.